# c# HtmlAgilityPack read non html tags

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, html-agility-pack

am trying to read MYOWNTAG using HtmlAgilityPack but I get  Object reference not set to an instance of an objec

 how can I print the name ahmed 
 this is my c# code

```
 string html = "<p>HELLO <MYOWNTAG> ahmed </MYOWNTAG> again</p>";

        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);
        foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//MYOWNTAG"))
                MessageBox.Show(node.InnerText);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string html = "<p>HELLO <MYOWNTAG> ahmed </MYOWNTAG> again</p>";

    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);
    foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//myowntag"))
            MessageBox.Show(node.InnerText);
```

It works. HtmlAgilityPack did ToLower() for all tags.

Comment: now it works so the problem was am reading the tag in uppercase